# Linker error, any ideas/explanation?

Tags: c++, directx

Been following along with a tutorial for direct x.  My most recent compile cam up with an entire slew of what I think are linker errors.  I don't know if it is specific to me or not.  I have the code [here](http://pastebin.com/cD9Ji4Zu) if anybody want to take a kick at the can.  Otherwise, any tips on fixing the errors?  They're mostly '__in' has not been declared and expected ',' or '...' before '&' token within some header file DXGI.h

Errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\dxgi.h|286|error: '__in' has not been declared|
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\dxgi.h|286|error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token|
```

Are the first two and Im getting this warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\DXGI.h|9|warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]|
```

I've tried swapping out the DXGI.h file and it still doesn't work along with trying the tutorials exact code(copy and paste) to eliminate chance for error.

Update:  Just tried it on an alternate computer and errored out as well.

Comment: Those would not be linker errors, but compile errors. You need to post some snippet of an example the kind of output you are getting. Also, what compiler and SDKs are you using?

Comment: The beginning of the error listing would be helpful.  Especially the line number.  One error can cause the cascade of errors, so just attack the first one.

Comment: There made an edit with the first two errors.  Also using mingw gcc compiler.